# echo $PATH doesn't match .bash_profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, path, terminal, homebrew

I'm attempting to install homebrew on Mountain Lion so that I can install Ruby 1.9.3.  After years of programming only PHP, 'm finally taking the jump into Rails, Git, etc.  In anycase, I'm on a laptop that was given to me.  Therefore, my login account is not the original account.  I think that might be causing the problem I'm having.

When running brew doctor I get the following:

> Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your path.
>   Consider amending your PATH variable so it contains:
>    /usr/local/sbin

When running echo $PATH I get the following:

> /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/chadimoglou/.rvm/bin

There is no .profile in my home directory.  There is a .bash_profile.  It looks like this

> [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

Any help for this terminal noob is much appreciated.

Comment: What about your `.bashrc`?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply @OliCharlesworth. My .bashrc shows as follows:
> PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

Should I add /usr/local/sbin into that?  How would I do that?

Comment: Restarting terminal after adding the string below worked perfect.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in your .bash_profile, you can simply do:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin"
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @wless1  I added that to the first line of .bash_profile and ran brew doctor again.  The result is the same.
> Consider amending your PATH variable so it contains:
>  /usr/local/sbin

Could echo $PATH be pulling from my .bashrc as shown in the response to Oli above?

Comment: Restarting terminal after adding the string worked perfect.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You can also reload your config files with `source ~/.bash_profile` or `. ~/.bash_profile` (dot is an alias for source).

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit your `$PATH` and `/bin`. [This guide](http://ubuntulinuxknowhow.blogspot.com/2013/06/what-are-path-and-bin-used-for.html) was not too terrible it helped me understand the entire concept of `$PATH /bin` and being a sudoer.