# echo $PATH different from /etc/profile?

Tags: unix, gentoo

`etc/profile`:

```
if [ "$EUID" = "0" ] || [ "$USER" = "root" ] ; then
        PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:${ROOTPATH}"
else
        PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:${PATH}"
fi
export PATH
unset ROOTPATH
```

`echo $PATH`:

```
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

So:

```
/usr/local/bin is not showing up, so I think it may be using a different file.
```

I have tried putting export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin and it's fine but that is not permanent.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be moved to "Unix & Linux"?

Comment: please don't comment unless you have some value to contribute: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631173/adding-a-path-to-the-bashrc-file, [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175773/echo-path-doesnt-match-bash-profile

Answer (score 1):

Check your shell init files, for bash that would be `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` or something like that as well as `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`. Most shells have similiar init scripts, check the manual.

Also check out `/etc/env.d/*` and `/etc/environment`.

Comment: I've checked `bashrc`...there's nothing specified regarding `$PATH`...also I have read that it is better practise to use profile instead of bashrc...I've checked the environment globals and I see the path `/opt/bin` alot.

Comment: Did you also check the init files in `/etc`?

Comment: No. There are environment files, too: `/etc/environment` and all files in `/etc/env.d/`. For example, my `PATH` variable is set by `/etc/env.d/00basic` and modified by `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Yes. Already responded...in `00basic` it says `PATH="/opt/bin"` as alluded to above. Nothing in `environment`.